# Equivalence of Norms on Incomplete Fields

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Then
are norms on $V$ equivalent when $\mathbb{F}$ is incomplete (i.e.,
lacks LUB property)? If not, what's a counterexample when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$?

Background: an analysis course asked to prove the equivalence of norms when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. My proof used completeness to show the
$\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{1}$ unit-sphere in $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ is compact (w.r.t the $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{1}$ induced metric).

How to show $S=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{F}^{n}:\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{1}=1\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{F}^{n}$
is compact without completeness of $\mathbb{F}$? More broadly, how to show norm-equivalence without completeness of $\mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical in number theory:

Let $V:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})=\{ a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b\in\mathbb Q \}$ be a two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

We can define two norms on $V$:

(1) $\|a+b\sqrt{2}\|_1 = |a+b\sqrt{2}|$ be the usual absolute value.

(2) $\|a+b\sqrt{2}\|_2 = |a-b\sqrt{2}|$.

Then under norm $1$, the sequence $\{(1-\sqrt 2)^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ goes to $0$ as its norm goes to $0$, but diverges according to $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Comment: clarification: how would $\left\Vert a+\sqrt{2}b\right\Vert _{2}=\left|a-\sqrt{2}\right|$
be homogeneous? Does it mean $\left\Vert a+\sqrt{2}b\right\Vert _{2}=\left|a-\sqrt{2}b\right|$?

Comment: You're right, that's a typo. Corrected.